# How do I view CSS styles that apply to an HTML element in watir-webdriver?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am using watir-webdriver and am attempting to check the background-color of an HTML element. The problem is that the background-color is set in the CSS and not inside the HTML tag.

Is there a way to read the CSS value using watir-webdriver?

Comment: I do not believe this capability exists because how the color was already decided upon is processed in the app server, web server, or browser engine. Expecting a test tool to show you what happened is to require a tool that will reverse engineer the web page source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, use the style method

Example:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.start 'minesweeper.github.com'
puts b.div(:id => 'g1minesRemaining100s').style 'background-image'
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Is there any documentation that would of led me to this? Calling the style method with no parameters doesn't return this information and the API docs I refer to don't go into detail for this method.

Comment: mmmm. I'm not sure. I have raised a bug to return style info when passing no parameters: https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/issues/120